# SWT Composite constructor throws IllegalArgumentException on a non-null argument

Tags: java, scala, swt

This piece of code (in Scala)

```
val contents = {
  assert(mainWindow.detailsPane != null)
  new Composite(mainWindow.detailsPane, SWT.NONE)
}
```

throws an exception:

```
Exception occurred
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkParent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.scala.NodeViewPresenter$NodeViewImpl.<init>(NodeViewPresenter.scala:41)
```

According to the [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html), `IllegalArgumentException` should only be thrown when the parent is `null`, but I am checking for that. `detailsPane` is a `CTabFolder`. Why this could happen?

Comment: I didn't tag it Scala, because I believed it was purely an SWT question (and it turned out to be correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution given [at the Eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&&th=168351&goto=534130#msg_534130): `detailsPane` turned out to be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the widget is disposed?

EDIT: did not see you answer there ;)